# Why does joining two related CSV files by using a join clause produce a single element instead of a sequence of elements?

Tags: c#, linq, csv, join

I want to merge two CSV files based on matching values. The two CSV files are related by the ID field which is the third <strike>column</strike> field in the first CSV file (names.csv), and the first <strike>column</strike> field in the second CSV file (scores.csv).

names.csv:

```
Adams,Terry,120  
Fakhouri,Fadi,116  
Feng,Hanying,117  
Garcia,Cesar,114  
Garcia,Debra,115  
Garcia,Hugo,118  
Mortensen,Sven,113  
O'Donnell,Claire,112  
Omelchenko,Svetlana,111  
Tucker,Lance,119  
Tucker,Michael,122  
Zabokritski,Eugene,121
```

scores.csv:

```
111, 97, 92, 81, 60  
112, 75, 84, 91, 39  
113, 88, 94, 65, 91  
114, 97, 89, 85, 82  
115, 35, 72, 91, 70  
116, 99, 86, 90, 94  
117, 93, 92, 80, 87  
118, 92, 90, 83, 78  
119, 68, 79, 88, 92  
120, 99, 82, 81, 79  
121, 96, 85, 91, 60  
122, 94, 92, 91, 91
```

### Code

```
            string[] names = File.ReadAllLines(@"/Users/username/Projects/ProjectA/names.csv");
            string[] marks = File.ReadAllLines(@"/Users/username/Projects/ProjectA/scores.csv");


            IEnumerable<Student> queryStudents =
                from name in names
                join mark in marks on name.Split(",")[2] equals mark.Split(',')[0]
                select new Student
                {
                    FirstName = name.Split(',')[0],
                    LastName = name.Split(',')[1],
                    ID = mark.Split(',')[0],
                    Scores = new List<int>
                  {int.Parse(mark.Split(',')[1]),
                  int.Parse(mark.Split(',')[2]),
                  int.Parse(mark.Split(',')[3]),
                  int.Parse(mark.Split(',')[4])
                  }
                };

            List<Student> students = queryStudents.ToList();

            foreach (Student student in students)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The average score of {0} {1} is {2}.", student.FirstName, student.LastName, student.Scores.Average());
            }
```

I expect the following output from the above query named `queryStudents`:

```
The average score of Omelchenko Svetlana is 82.5.
    The average score of O'Donnell Claire is 72.25.
    The average score of Mortensen Sven is 84.5.
    The average score of Garcia Cesar is 88.25.
    The average score of Garcia Debra is 67.
    The average score of Fakhouri Fadi is 92.25.
    The average score of Feng Hanying is 88.
    The average score of Garcia Hugo is 85.75.
    The average score of Tucker Lance is 81.75.
    The average score of Adams Terry is 85.25.
    The average score of Zabokritski Eugene is 83.
    The average score of Tucker Michael is 92.
```

However I only get a single element when the query `queryStudents` is executed:

```
The average score of Zabokritski Eugene is 83.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that names.csv has extra spaces at the end of the id fields, except for the last one. That is why the record for Zabokritski,Eugene appears correctly in the output.

You could fix this by changing this line:

```
join mark in marks on name.Split(",")[2] equals mark.Split(',')[0]
```

To trim the spaces before comparison, like this:

```
join mark in marks on name.Split(",")[2].Trim() equals mark.Split(',')[0].Trim()
```

However, there's quite a lot going on in this small section of code. I found it easier when debugging this to break this up into separate methods each with a specific purpose (e.g. a method to create names, a separate method for scores, a method to join the results)

**Update:** As requested, here's how I split update the code when debugging. This is much longer than your version (and I'm not saying this is the best way to write the code) but for me it made it easier to understand each section of the code and track down the problem:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] names = File.ReadAllLines(@"/Users/username/Projects/ProjectA/names.csv");
            string[] marks = File.ReadAllLines(@"/Users/username/Projects/ProjectA/scores.csv");

            var students = CreateStudents(names);
            var scores = CreateScores(marks);
            var averageScores = CreateAverageScores(students, scores);

            DisplayResults(averageScores);
        }

        private static List<Student> CreateStudents(string[] names)
        {
            return names.Select(name => new Student
            {
                FirstName = name.Split(',')[0],
                LastName = name.Split(',')[1], 
                ID = name.Split(',')[2].Trim()
            }).ToList();
        }

        private static List<Score> CreateScores(string[] marks)
        {
            return marks.Select(mark => new Score
            {
                ID = mark.Split(',')[0].Trim(),
                Values = new List<int>
                {
                    int.Parse(mark.Split(',')[1]),
                    int.Parse(mark.Split(',')[2]),
                    int.Parse(mark.Split(',')[3]),
                    int.Parse(mark.Split(',')[4])
                }
            }).ToList();
        }

        private static IEnumerable<AverageScore> CreateAverageScores(List<Student> students, List<Score> scores)
        {
            var studentScores =
                from student in students
                join score in scores on student.ID equals score.ID
                select new AverageScore
                {
                    FirstName = student.FirstName,
                    LastName = student.LastName,
                    Average = score.Values.Average()
                };
            return studentScores;
        }

        private static void DisplayResults(IEnumerable<AverageScore> studentScores)
        {
            foreach (var studentScore in studentScores)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The average score of {0} {1} is {2}.", studentScore.FirstName, studentScore.LastName,
                    studentScore.Average);
            }
        }
```

Comment: That was it! Thanks. I'm interested in how you created a method to "join the results". Can you add to your answer your code showing how you broke down my code into separate methods that each create names, create scores, join the results etc.?

Comment: No problem. Update added as requested.